How do I get geom_bar() to sufficiently dodge each other + be grayscale / black and white?
I am trying to get the colored bars to 'dodge' each other when using geom_bar to plot them. I am also trying to change the color of the bars to just black and white or grayscale. However, I am struggling Googling around to find out why I can't do either. How do you do either? Thank you for your help!

p <- ggplot() + 
geom_bar(aes(x = factor(Pre$preQ17), fill = factor("Pre-Panel")), alpha = 0.5) +
geom_bar(aes(x = factor(Post$postQ7), fill = factor("Post-Panel")), alpha = 0.5, position="dodge") +
labs(title = "Impressions of Prevalence of All Rare Diseases Combined", x = "Prevalence", y = "Number of students", fill = "Survey") + 
scale_x_discrete(labels= c("1 in 2", "1 in 5", "1 in 10", "1 in 100", "1 in 1,000", "1 in 10,000", "1 in 100,000")) + 
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white')) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p

res <- t.test(Pre$preQ17,Post$postQ7)
res


Output with current code above
I have tried to use ggplot() instead but this has not been successful. I am not a great coder.

I can't reproduce your dataset with the information provided. Please see link here on how to ask a minimal, reproducible example.
Nevertheless, does this help answer your question?
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer %in% c('audi', 'toyota')) %>% # data wrangling
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cty, fill = manufacturer),
           position = 'dodge') + # side-by-side rather than stacked
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('audi' = 'black', 'toyota' = 'gray')) + # set custom colors
  theme_minimal()


Created on 2024-06-20 with reprex v2.1.0

If you want to keep the two geom_bar() as they are, add just and width params. You can shift the bars left with just = 1 and right with just = 0. (The default is .5 for centered. Make the bars narrower with width.
For example:
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(Pre$preQ17)),  stat = "count", just = 1.05, width = .4, colour = "black", fill = "transparent") +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(Post$postQ17)), stat = "count", just = -0.05, width = .4, colour = "grey", fill = "transparent")

